# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZoomLevelLimits' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron

I ran into the following error after trying to start my electron app via `npm start`. Here's the error message:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZoomLevelLimits' of undefined`

Below is the code:

```
const electron = require("electron").webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;


let mainWindow;

app.on("ready", function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    kiosk: true
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/index.html");

  // Debug3
  // mainWindow.openDevTools({ detach: true });
});
```

I am trying to prevent user for dragging and zooming in the screen on my desktop app, and `website-user-drag: none` doesn't work as well as this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> const electron = require("electron").webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);

1. The `webFrame` module in only available in the renderer process, you're attempting to access it in the main/browser process.
2. Even if `webFrame` was available in the main process `setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1)` doesn't return a reference to the `electron` module so the rest of your code won't work because `const electron` will be `undefined`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What would then be your solution?

Comment: @John You need to call `require("electron").webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1)` in the renderer process, you can do that inside a `<script>` tag in your `index.html` (or any script/module you directly or indirectly load via `index.html`).

Comment: thanks. Would by chance be another workaround via css to solve this?